# what is the error in the given query

Tags: mysql

While a am executing the query

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), 'select lastLoginTime from requests where id = 2 ')
```

Its returning NULL. Any idea why??

Comment: It is not returning `NULL`, it is returning `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2' ')' at line 1`. Strings are not [subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html).

Comment: Replace your string with an actual subquery. After you read [the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html).

Comment: My bad.. Corrected the query, its returning NULL.

Comment: I don't see how you have corrected it, except that your string is now actually valid, but is still not a subquery. Probably it would help if you do read the docs after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), 'select last_update from t1 where actor_id = 2 ');
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), 'select last_update from t1 where actor_id = 2 ') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                           NULL |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

remove the ' and add ()

```
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), (select last_update from t1 where actor_id = 2));
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), (select last_update from t1 where actor_id = 2)) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                    -199167725 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```